# Filtering tarfile.add using individual file names

Tags: python, tarfile

Is there a way to access the individual file names in the `filter` lambda when adding a directory using `tarfile.add`?

I'm using the `tarfile` module to create archives of project directories.  Some of these files I no longer need, and I'd like to ignore:

```
myproj/  # example; actual project directory structure much deeper
    importantfile.txt
    semi-importantfile.doc
    useless-file.exe  # ignore this one
```

What I am doing right now is using `tarfile.add`'s `exclude` parameter to skip `useless-file.exe`.

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open('mytar.tar', 'w') as mytar:
    mytar.add('myproj', exclude=lambda x: os.path.basename(x) == 'useless-file.exe')
```

I'm aware that `exclude` is now deprecated, and in the interest of future-proofing I'm trying to switch to using the new `filter` parameter.

```
    mytar.add('myproj', filter=lambda x: (
                                x if x.name != 'useless-file.exe'
                                else None))
```

However, doing this ends up adding `useless-file.exe` to the tarball.  With some tests I discovered this is because, while `exclude` is fed the name of the directory and all its contents recursively, `filter` only gets the `TarInfo` for the file explicitly being added (in this case, the directory `myproj`)

So is there a way to replicate the behavior I had with `exclude` using `filter`?  If it's possible, I would really rather not iterate through all of my directories recursively just to check that I don't add any unwanted files.

#### Explanation of Solution

See @larsks's answer for a complete explanation of the problem.  My issue was when using `exclude` I called `os.path.basename` on `x` (see edited code above), but I forgot to do it on `x.name` when using `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `filter` method behaves the way you think it does.  For example, if I have a directory structure that looks like:

```
example/
  file0.1
  file0.2
  dir1/
    file1.1
    file1.2
```

And I run the following code:

```
import tarfile

def myfilter(thing):
    print('myfilter called for {thing.name}'.format(thing=thing))
    return thing

t = tarfile.open('archive.tar', mode='w')
t.add('example', recursive=True, filter=myfilter)
```

I see as output:

```
myfilter called for example
myfilter called for example/file0.1
myfilter called for example/file0.2
myfilter called for example/dir1
myfilter called for example/dir1/file1.1
myfilter called for example/dir1/file1.2
```

That is, the filter is getting called once per item added to the archive.  If wanted to exclude `example/dir1/file1.1`, I would write a filter function that looked something like this:

```
def exclude_file1(thing):
    if thing.name != 'example/dir1/file1.1':
        return thing
```

When using this as the filter in the above example, the resulting archive contains:

```
$ tar tf archive.tar 
example/
example/file0.1
example/file0.2
example/dir1/
example/dir1/file1.2
```

(**edit**: the above example was tested with Python 3.5)